Google Document AI Fine Tuning is taking forever
I am using a foundational model "pretrained-foundation-model-v1.1-2024-03-12" to train a custom extractor on Google Document AI. I've set the epochs to 300 and Learning Rate to 1 (range is btw 0.1 to 10). I started the training yesterday at 21:33 and it is still training. My dataset split is 52 PDFs for training and 25 PDFs for testing.

I tried to disable the processor and start a new one but the training doesn't stop even if i disable the processor.

Hi @Sri Ram M S, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support Case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue trackerdescribing your issue
